# Vuejs - Dynamically change the :items of a datatable based on the current tab

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I started learning Vue and I am stuck in a project of mine. I am using vuetify.

I want to have some tabs and based on the tab that the user selects to show the appropriate data in a datatable. I just need one datatable which based on the selection the :items should change automatically.

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-tabs
                v-model="tab"
                background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
                centered
                dark
                icons-and-text
        >
            <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>

            <v-tab href="#tab1">
                somethng
            </v-tab>

            <v-tab href="#tab2">
                    something
            </v-tab>
        </v-tabs>    
        <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
            <v-data-table
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="tab"
                    :items-per-page="5"
                    class="elevation-1"
            >
            </v-data-table>
        </v-tabs-items>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        data() {
            return {
                tab: null,
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: 'Description',
                        align: 'start',
                        sortable: true,
                        value: 'description',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Link',
                        align: 'start',
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'link',
                    }

                ],

                tab1: [
                    {description: "test", link: "test"},
                ],

                tab2: [
                    {description: "test", link: "test"},                        
                ],
                
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

So basically I kinda need to translate the tab value from string to the corresponding array. I didn’t find something similar and whatever I tried it has failed.

for example I have tried using a watcher but then I got an error that the :items table just reads arrays.

I don't want to have multiple datatables and make use of the `v-if` if that can be avoided. If it can't only then I want to use it

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put a function in [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) section.
For example:

```
computed: {
    items: function () {
        switch (this.tab) {
            case 1:
                return [/*first array*/];
            case 2:
                return [/*second array*/];
            case 3:
                return [/*third array*/];
            default:
                return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works 100%. What I was doing with the computed property was to return the tab name inside items with the logic that it will match it with the appropriate array inside data...silly me